# How do I pass array variables into SED?

Tags: arrays, bash, sed, substitution

I'm attempting a Caesar Cipher using SED to convert a text file into a ciphered text file. Currently, I'm attempting to use two arrays, one from a to z and the other from z to a. However, SED is throwing strange errors ("sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command).

```
#!/bin/bash

#Substitute the inOrder with the reverseOrder

inOrder=();
reverseOrder=();

for w in {a..z}
do
    inOrder+=(${w})
done

for z in {z..a}
do
    reverseOrder+=(${z})
done

echo ${inOrder[@]}
echo ${reverseOrder[@]}

sed -i 's/'${inOrder[@]}'/'${reverseOrder[@]}'/g' new.txt
```

Comment: The command you are looking for in sed is called translate `y/abcde/edcba/' however the translate command `tr` is altogether more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is the fact that you do not keep the script argument as one argument.

`${inOrder[@]}` is `a b c d ... y z`. Note the spaces. When you substitute it into your `sed` command, you get this:

```
set -i 's/'a b c d ... y z'/'z y ... d c b a'/g/' new.txt
```

which is identical to

```
set -i 's/a' b c d ... y 'z/z' y ... d c b 'a/g/' new.txt
```

so your script is `s/a`, working on a bunch of weird files (`b`, `c`, `d`, ... `y`, `z/z` and `y` again... and a `a/g/` directory). In `s/a`, you can see the substitution command not being terminated.

What you would need here is to doubly-quote to keep the expansion as one argument: `"s/${inOrder[@]}..."` or `'s/'"$inOrder[@]"...`

However, that still does not solve your task, because you are trying to substitute the entire string `a b c d ... y z` with the reversed string, but presumably such a string is not found in your data, so it would fail. Also, Caesar Cypher involves substituting letters, not alphabet recitals. Instead, you want `tr`, which does single-character substitutions.

```
inOrder=`echo {a..z} | tr -d ' '`
reverseOrder=`echo {z..a} | tr -d ' '`

echo $inOrder
echo $reverseOrder

tr $inOrder $reverseOrder < new.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that fits my needs. Thank you so much for you guys' suggestions!

```
#!/bin/bash

#Retrieve the desired shift from user
echo "What number do you want to use for the shift?"
read num

#Create an array of all letters
x=({a..z})

#Take user input and use to create the cipher array
case "$num" in
    0)
    y=({a..z})
    ;;
    1)
    y=({{b..z},a})
    ;;
    2)
    y=({{c..z},a,b})
    ;;
    3)
    y=({{d..z},a,b,c})
    ;;
    4)
    y=({{e..z},a,b,c,d})
    ;;
    5)
    y=({{f..z},{a..e}})
    ;;
    6)
    y=({{g..z},{a..f}})
    ;;  
    7)
    y=({{h..z},{a..g}})
    ;;
    8)
    y=({{i..z},{a..h}})
    ;;
    9)
    y=({{j..z},{a..i}})
    ;;
    10)
    y=({{k..z},{a..j}})
    ;;
    11)
    y=({{l..z},{a..k}})
    ;;
    12)
    y=({{m..z},{a..l}})
    ;;
    13)
    y=({{n..z},{a..m}})
    ;;
    14)
    y=({{o..z},{a..n}})
    ;;
    15)
    y=({{p..z},{a..o}})
    ;;
    16)
    y=({{q..z},{a..p}})
    ;;
    17)
    y=({{r..z},{a..q}})
    ;;
    18)
    y=({{s..z},{a..r}})
    ;;
    19)
    y=({{t..z},{a..s}})
    ;;
    20)
    y=({{u..z},{a..t}})
    ;;
    21)
    y=({{v..z},{a..u}})
    ;;
    22)
    y=({{w..z},{a..v}})
    ;;
    23)
    y=({{x..z},{a..w}})
    ;;
    24)
    y=({{y..z},{a..x}})
    ;;
    25)
    y=({{z..z},{a..y}})
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Sorry, you must use a shift from 0 to 25."
    ;;
esac

#create the string variables for manipulation
fromset=""
toset=""

#place the alphabetic arrays into the atring variables
for i in {0..25}
do
    fromset="$fromset${x[i]}"
    toset="$toset${y[i]}"
done

#Use sed text transformations to alter given files
sed "y/$fromset/$toset/" original.txt > encoded.txt
sed "y/$toset/$fromset/" encoded.txt > decoded.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't that almost repetition make your skin creep?  It should!  There has to be a better way than writing out almost the same the code 26 times.  Your notation like `y=({{l..z},{a..k}})` could also be written `y=({l..z} {a..k})`.  The asymmetry between the lists like `y=({{c..z},a,b})` and `y=({{y..z},{a..x}})` is puzzling too.  If you're going to do it this way, be ruthlessly systematic and symmetric.

Comment: You're correct. Later (when I have more time), I plan to create a for-loop that replaces or helps out the switch statement.